# calculate the difference between groups as a percentage

Tags: r, dataframe, difference

I have a date frame:

```
data <- structure(list(col1 = c(10L, 8L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 3L), col2 = c(11L, 
9L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 6L), col3 = c(12L, 10L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 7L), group = c("a", 
"a", "b", "b", "c", "c")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

I would like to find the difference between all the groups (a -b;a-c; b-c) and also calculate how many percent of the number is from the number (the first number is taken as 100%)

What I want to get:

[image]

Comment: Can you explain the calculation  here?  Why `col1_new` has only one number as percentage and rest of them 2? How do you calculate the percentage ?

Comment: 'a','a',b','b' so there must 4 pairs 'a-b','a-b','a-b','a-b'. isnt it ?

Comment: I subtract in pairs, the first number is taken for 100%, then it is subtracted and calculated how many percent is the number of the number. For example, col1_new is calculated as follows from col1 10 from group a it is 100% then we subtract group b 5 we get 5 it is 50% of 10, then from 8 from group a I subtract 4 from group b I get 4 it is 50% of 8 and so on

Comment: Can you explain an example for `col2_new` then? Why there are 2 numbers there? (45, 45%)

Comment: ", "is the same as". " these are fractions of a number. 11 is 100% of group a we subtract 6 from group b we get 5 is 45.45% of 11. the second value of 9 is 100% of group a we subtract the second value of 4 from group b we get 5 is 55.56% of 9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a base R approach using `combn` -

```
do.call(rbind, combn(unique(data$group), 2, function(x) {
  dt1 <- subset(data, group == x[1])
  dt2 <- subset(data, group == x[2])
  val1 <- abs(dt1[-4] - dt2[-4])
  val2 <- val1/dt1[-4]
  val2[] <- sprintf('%s (%s %%)', round(as.matrix(val1), 2),
                                  round(as.matrix(val2) * 100, 2))
  data.frame(val2, group = paste0(x, collapse = '-'))
}, simplify = FALSE))

#         col1        col2        col3 group
#1    5 (50 %) 5 (45.45 %) 5 (41.67 %)   a-b
#2    4 (50 %) 6 (66.67 %)    5 (50 %)   a-b
#3    4 (40 %) 7 (63.64 %) 5 (41.67 %)   a-c
#4  5 (62.5 %) 3 (33.33 %)    3 (30 %)   a-c
#31   1 (20 %) 2 (33.33 %)     0 (0 %)   b-c
#41   1 (25 %)   3 (100 %)    2 (40 %)   b-c
```